# td class to $_SESSION multi pages

Tags: php, session

im using this in php page To Show First And Last Name in page

```
<tr><td class="initialtext">your firstname : <? echo $name[0][0]; ?></td></tr> 
<tr><td class="initialtext">your lastname : <? echo $name[0][1]; ?></td></tr>
```

, But i would like to show names in others pages by using

```
$_SESSION['lastname']
$_SESSION['firstname']
```

Please help me to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: so whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: read the tutorial on sessions then... http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;

    echo $_SESSION['lastname'];

?>
```

Comment: Thank you , but it doesnt work , still empty in the other pages !

Comment: You must add `session_start();` at the beginning of every page in which you want to use `$_SESSION`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help
I've fixed the problem ^_^

i've replace

```
<? echo $name[0][1]; ?>
```

with

```
<? echo $name[1][1]; ?>
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.